# How to add a method to module express() with using util?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to expand the express module, and add to his my method.
for this I use util module
My piece of code:

```
var expressApplication = require('express');
var util = require('util');

function Application() {
    expressApplication.apply(this, arguments);
    this.handlers = {};
}
util.inherits(Application, expressApplication);

//add my method
Application.prototype.write = function(data) {
    console.log(data)
};
```

Then I call it:

```
var app = new Application();

//check inheritance
console.log(app instanceof expressApplication); // true
console.log(Application.super_ === expressApplication); // true

//and check the work my method
console.log(app.write('test'));


console.log(app.use) /// ---> error!!!
```

But when I want to call the method of the express - it is not available to me,`console.log(app.use)` has error `app.use is not a function`

Please tell me what is wrong, where to look to fix the problem? Alternatively, instead I auditioned express koa, there is practiced.

Thanks!

Comment: did you forget to pass something to use()? http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

Comment: no, i didnt forget ().  If output to the console `console.log(app.write)`  he return `[Function]`. But `console.log(app.use)` return `undefined`. there is no inheritance of  `express` and i dont understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function exported by `require('express')` is merely a [factory function](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e71014f522fb8db9ba1ef634f2e9f2c8069e4b6c/lib/express.js#L27-L48) that does its own prototype mixing, so there isn't really one object to inherit from.

You have a couple of options:

- Copy Express's factory function that uses your own `express.application` subclass
- Directly modify the original `express.application`

The benefit of the first one is that you don't affect all Express app instances, which is typically what you'd want. Writing to prototypes of third party modules (or even built-in objects for that matter) is generally frowned upon and can cause problems (especially if end users attach their own properties with the same names).

Comment: Tell me how to use the first option is better?